# Android SQLite: Query to retrive only 5 records at a time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sqlite

I need to retrieve data from a table QUESTION_TABLE with a limit of only 5 records at a time and display them in the Different textviews and these questions have answers of yes or a no , and when next button is clicked after submitting the first 5 answers of questions , a new set of next 5 questions should be displayed with the radiobuttons  refreshed and these options should be stored in the same table and later are utilised with permutaions and combinations and results are displayed, How can I achieve this?

And is View Flipper necessary for the textviews to change the questions which are retrieved from the database with a limit of 5?

This is my questions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="110sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50sp" >

            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
                android:layout_width="425dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="425dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:text="" />

            </ViewFlipper>
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/questionyesno1" >

            <RadioGroup 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/question1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/yes1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yes" 
                android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/no1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>    
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="110sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50sp" >

            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/viewFlipper2"
                android:layout_width="425dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="425dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:text="" />

            </ViewFlipper>


               <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/questionyesno2" >

            <RadioGroup 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/question2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/yes2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yes" 
                android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/no2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            </RadioGroup>



</LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="110sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50sp" >

            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/viewFlipper3"
                    android:layout_width="425dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="425dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:text=""/>

            </ViewFlipper>



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/questionyesno3" >

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/question3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/yes3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Yes"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="35sp"
                            android:textStyle="italic" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/no3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="No"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="35sp"
                            android:textStyle="italic" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="110sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50sp" >

            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/viewFlipper4"
                    android:layout_width="425dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:text="" />

            </ViewFlipper>
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/questionyesno4" >

            <RadioGroup 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/question4"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/yes4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yes" 
                android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/no4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="110sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50sp" >

            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/viewFlipper5"
                    android:layout_width="425dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:text="" />

            </ViewFlipper>
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/questionyesno5" >

            <RadioGroup 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/question5"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/yes5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yes" 
                android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/no5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.12" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submitb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70sp"
                android:text="Next"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110sp"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110sp"
                android:text="Skip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:background="#ffffff" />
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Any HINTS  or any code snippets will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you need a lot of stuff...

Comment: so where is your code-behind?

Comment: I'm thinking about converting the yes no options in to binary 0 and 1 and save them in the db and they retrive them accordingly with the permutaions and combinations of answers given for the questions and show the result  , more hints or other approach can be really helpful , thank you

Answer (score 0):

I thik you can do the job using sqlite limit statement like this

```
select * from your_table where <condition> order by <order condition> limit 5,X
```

this query will select only 5 records starting from the one at position X

you just need to remember how many sets of questions you have already shown to pass the correct value of X

hope this help